# hash passwords not matching

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I'm using the functions below.  When I register a user, the hash seems to work fine.  When I try to login the hash doesn't match.  It has the correct hash, plus extra hash.

What's the issue?

```
function salt($pass){
$salt = 'hello';
return hash('sha512', $pass.$salt);
}

function valid_credentials($user,$pass) {
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$pass = salt($pass);
$total = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '".$user."' AND `password` = '{$pass}' ");
return (mysql_result($total, 0) == '1' ) ? true : false;
}

function add_user($user, $pass) {
$user = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($user));
$pass = salt($pass);
$time = now();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ( user_name, password, date_created ) VALUES ( '{$user}', '{$pass}', '{$time}' )");
}
```

Comment: Just a side note... Your salt is not very good. With a word like hello in your salt table, some of your users passwords are still going to end up in a rainbow table and if they get more than one, they are going to know the scheme and have a much easier time cracking it. I would make it a long random string with non alpha numeric characters.

Comment: Yes, I'm only using that as an example.

Comment: SOLVED. I'm a dumbass.  My column length wasn't long enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your validation code this line:

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '".$user."' AND `password` = '{$pass}' ");
```

needs to be changed to something like so:

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '".$user."' AND `password` = '".$pass."' ");
```

Right now it appears to be checking for the password column being equal to "{$pass}".

Answer (score 1):

just double check your value returned before and after inserting the value to db table. Echo it with a trim function. or use strcmp to check the values that is inserted in the db with your generated value.